# Batch Files - How can I replace a word after finding it?

Tags: batch-file

I am using batch to create variables for another program (which I did not make). I need to modify these strings; but not replace the whole file (it is very long). However, when researching the topic, many people just suggest the `findstr` command (which finds BUT does NOT replace string). Is there any way to replace a string rather than rewrite the whole file?

Example Text:

```
Oh it's a lovely day
```

Changes in bold:

**o**h it's a **new** day

(Instead of rewriting the whole text, it just effects certain areas.

Comment: There is no shortcut in batch to modify one line in a file; you have to read the entire file, and then write out a modified version of the file.  (There's no shortcut in any other language either; unless the new line is the same length as the old, you have to rewrite every byte after that line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [batch string substitution](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html); here I assumed that what needs to be replaced is:

- the whole phrase: *Oh it's a lovely day* - *oh it's a new day*

Go through the file line by line and do the replacements. Here's the code:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (.\a.txt) do (
    call :replace_func %%f
)
goto :eof

:replace_func
    set _local0=%*
    if "%_local0%" equ "" goto :eof
    :echo l0 %_local0%
    echo %_local0:Oh it's a lovely day=oh it's a new day%
    goto :eof
```

The string substitution happens in `replace_func`, while the file is being iterated in the `for` loop.

For the *a.txt* file contents:

> Oh it's a lovely day1
>
> Some other text
>
> Oh it's a lovely day2
>
> Oh it's a lovely day3
>
> lovely day

the output would be:

> oh it's a new day1
>
> Some other text
>
> oh it's a new day2
>
> oh it's a new day3
>
> lovely day

@EDIT1: rookie mistake: no "goto :eof" after the loop. The `if` clause hidden any garbage output generated by this.

Comment: Are you missing a `goto :eof` before the `:replace_func` label?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace strings in a batch file using the following command:

```
set str="Oh it's a lovely day"
set str=%str:O=o%
set str=%str:lovely=new%
```

And will get in 'str': `oh it's a new day`